# Drupal: how to see the query when the node is created or any content type is created

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-views, drupal-modules, drupal-panels

I want to know the insert query when the content is created or any node is created.

What is a simple example for that?

The main purpose of doing this is I want to log the entries when the node is created.

So I have created a history content. When the user creates certain type of content, I have inserted his/her details in to the table by using rules and custom PHP.

It works fine. I can see in the database table but the problem is I can't see the details. When I create a view for the history table, they won't show up.

When I create the history content it displays in the view.

Maybe the inserting into the content have some dependencies, I don't know.

Answer (score 2):

The [Devel module](http://drupal.org/project/devel) can be used to see the queries that are executed on a Drupal page.

Comment: can u describe an example... 
i m newbie i am using devel module but i can see only the varaible values, no the query----

Comment: Take a look at the documentation here: http://ratatosk.backpackit.com/pub/1836982-debugging-drupal
You can use Devel in conjunction with Firebug, or even add PHP code to your theme to output debug info